# How to add facebook, twitter and Email in app about us screen (android)

Tags: android

i am new in android development, recently i created an app and i want to add facebook, twitter and Email in app about us screen.

what i want is exactly looks like: see screenshot:
http://s30.postimg.org/pnnkp39bl/Screenshot_2014_12_02_17_26_25.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a piece of code I used in one of my application. Just create a LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation. This way all views will be put next to each other. If you want all icons to have the same amount of space between them, you should use layout_weight in the subviews.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSocialMediaContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

         <!--Facebook-->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebookicon" />

        <!--Twitter-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twittericon" />

        <!--Google+-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/googleicon" />


        <!--Pinterest-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pinteresticon" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

After this, just put a onClickListener on the imageviews or buttons if you choose to use those. with the Intent that matches your purpose

Comment: how to give equal spaces between these images and how to add them at bottom

Comment: add `android:layout_weight=1` to the ImageViews. If you want them at the bottom of the screen, use a `RelativeLayout` as a parent, and put the LinearLayout in it. Give the `LinearLayout` the          `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`